# Issue with creating a pandas dataframe if filepath is a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a code that browse through a selected folder and checks for the files that contain a specific string. When a file is found, it creates an absolute path to pass it to a pandas data-frame.

```
for file in os.listdir(files_path):
   if str_tr in file:
      path= os.path.abspath(file)
      df[ctr] = pd.read_excel(path)
```

In this case the full path is :
[image]
But when I try to pass it to pandas I receive error :

[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
[image]
I think because of double slashes.
What can I do to fix it? Normally if it was a string I would use 'r' but in my case the path is in a variable.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Your code doesn't have proper indentation.

Comment: Try `path = os.path.join(files_path, file)` instead of `path= os.path.abspath(file)`.  The way you are doing it is trying to locate the file in the current working directory (specifically `os.getcwd()`) rather than in `files_path` (which is where you searched).

Comment: Additionally, the "double slashes" are just how single slashes are displayed.  `'\transactions'` is really the tab character + 'ansactions'.  To stop `\t` being interpreted as a tab the slash is written `\\ `.  This avoids those situations where the slash comes before an escape character (such as `\t` tab, `\n` newline, `\b` backspace, etc.).

Comment: in ```df[ctr]``` what is exactly ```ctr```?

Answer (score 0):

I think you neer to add r to the path before giving it to pandas:

```
for file in os.listdir(files_path):
    if str_tr in file:
    path= rf'{os.path.abspath(file)}' 
    df[ctr] = pd.read_excel(path)
```